# CSS transition not consistent

Tags: html, css, transition

```js
(function() {
    angular.module('transitionApp', [])
    .controller('headerCtrl', headerController);
  
    function headerController() {
        var self = this;
      
        self.isSearchOpen = false;
        self.toggleSearch = function() {
            
        }
    }
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="transitionApp">
 <div class="header" ng-controller="headerCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="search">
   <span>
    S
   </span>
   <input type="text">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have a css transition that changes the width of the div and the textbox.
The first time I open the search-component, the transition triggers normally. The first time it closes however, the event doesn't trigger at all, and the properties are changes without any kind of transition.

Afterwards, the transition works fine.

Upon refresh, the behavior is present again.

Here is a video of the bug:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_l1LEJhFUfg

Edit:
I use angularJS for the click/focus/blur events.

Any help regarding this issue, is appreciated!

Koen Morren

Comment: can you add your code in fiddle.net

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with your code.

Comment: yes, please provide code, but rather than using an external site, you can insert a snippet inline in your question and it can be run directly in the page - use the `<>` icon

Answer (score 0):

you can try this model hope you help:

```
(function(window){

    // get vars
    var searchEl = document.querySelector("#input");
    var labelEl = document.querySelector("#label");

    // register clicks and toggle classes
    labelEl.addEventListener("click",function(){
        if (classie.has(searchEl,"focus")) {
            classie.remove(searchEl,"focus");
            classie.remove(labelEl,"active");
        } else {
            classie.add(searchEl,"focus");
            classie.add(labelEl,"active");
        }
    });

    // register clicks outisde search box, and toggle correct classes
    document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        var clickedID = e.target.id;
        if (clickedID != "search-terms" && clickedID != "search-label") {
            if (classie.has(searchEl,"focus")) {
                classie.remove(searchEl,"focus");
                classie.remove(labelEl,"active");
            }
        }
    });
}(window));
```

[**Here this page**](http://callmenick.com/post/expanding-search-bar-using-css-transitions)